# Sending httprequest from localhost

Tags: php, ajax, httprequest

```
function PostRequest($url) { 
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Cookie: testcookie=blah; testcookie2=haha;'
        )
    );

    //$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);



    return $result; 
}
```

After I sent out the cookies, I still return by a message non login. but when I surf the pages with browser, I am login.
I sent request with localhost then I tried to used ajax to sent the request, but return status 0......

Is there any way to sent out the request?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with HTTP scripting, i have library which you can use. https://github.com/toopay/CI-Proxy-Library, its orriginally written for CodeIgniter, but with little tweak, you should can use it on any PHP script.

Comment: thx,but i just nid to sent cookies with file_get_contents.thx for ur code ^^